# What's a non-deterministic procedure?

Tags: complexity-theory, computer-science, np, non-deterministic

I have a problem...what's a nondeterministic procedure?
I have this exercise

Provide a nondeterministic procedure for the following language:
L = {: G=(V,E) has an Indipendent Set I s.t. |I| >= k and the vertices V\I form a Hamilton cycle}

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A non-deterministic procedure or function is a procedure that for a given input value will *not* always produce the same output.

For example:
DateTime.GetCurrent would be non-deterministic. Random.Next() would be non-deterministic. Math.Sin() would hopefully be deterministic. If you enter the same value 10 times you will get the same result 10 times.

Comment: Is this related to Non-deterministic polynomial problems?

Answer (score 0):

A non-deterministic function can rely on an "oracle". In your example, the oracle would produce the set `I` and the function only needs to check whether it has specified properties, i.e. `I` is independent, `|I| >= k` and `V\I` forms a Hamilton cycle.